# How to edit and pass a global variable onto several pages in Sveltekit?

Tags: javascript, global, svelte, sveltekit, state-management

On the landing page, a user will enter a dog breed they're looking for. After this is submitted, that value will be saved globally and the name of that breed will be passed into the new route. I tried using a store to update and call the value but no luck so far.

Store.js

```
import { writable } from "svelte/store";

const dog = writable("");

export default dog;
```

+page.svelte (Landing Page)

```
<script>
  let dog_val = "" 
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(dog_val);
    dog.set(dog_val)
   window.location.href = "/dog"
  }
</script>

<main>
  <input bind:value={dog_val} placeholder="Search for a dog breed" />
  <button on:click={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}>Search This Breed</button>
</main>
```

+page.svelte (Dog Page)

```
<script>
   let dog_val = "";
   dog.subscribe(prev_val => {dog_val = prev_val})
</script>

<main>
  <h1>{dog_val}</h1>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this line

```
import dog from 'path-to-dog.js';
```

To use an exported value/function from a file you must first import that file first.

So add this line in the first line after the script tag in `+page.svelte` like:

```
<script>
  import dog from 'path-to-dog.js';
  // the rest of the code...
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the misunderstanding but I had the import just didn't put it in the snippet here. Turns out the window.location.href was what was screwing it up so I replaced it with the goto method and it works!

Comment: Alright no worries!